# Can I run a small project with Kubernetes on GCP with one node (g1-small)?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I’m voluntarily operating (developing and hosting) a community project. Meaning time and money are tight. Currently it runs on a bare-metal machine at AWS (t2.micro, (1 vCPU, 1 GB memory)).
For learning purposes I would like to containerize my application. Now I'm looking for hosting. The Google Cloud Plattform seems to be the cheapest to me.
I setup a Kubernetes cluster with 1 node (1.10.9-gke.5, g1-small (1 vCPU shared, 1.7 GB memory)).

After I set up the one node Kubernetes cluster I checked how much memory and CPU is already used by the Kubernetes system. (Please see kubectl describe node).

I was wondering if I can run the following application with 30% CPU and 30% memory left on the node. Unfortunately I don't have experience with how much the container in my example will need in terms of resources. But having only 30% CPU and 30% memory left doesn't seem like much for my kind of application.

**kubectl describe node**

```
Non-terminated Pods:         (9 in total)
  Namespace                  Name                                                           CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits
  ---------                  ----                                                           ------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------
  kube-system                event-exporter-v0.2.3-54f94754f4-bznpk                         0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)
  kube-system                fluentd-gcp-scaler-6d7bbc67c5-pbrq4                            0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)
  kube-system                fluentd-gcp-v3.1.0-fjbz6                                       100m (10%)    0 (0%)      200Mi (17%)      300Mi (25%)
  kube-system                heapster-v1.5.3-66b7745959-4zbcl                               138m (14%)    138m (14%)  301456Ki (25%)   301456Ki (25%)
  kube-system                kube-dns-788979dc8f-krrtt                                      260m (27%)    0 (0%)      110Mi (9%)       170Mi (14%)
  kube-system                kube-dns-autoscaler-79b4b844b9-vl4mw                           20m (2%)      0 (0%)      10Mi (0%)        0 (0%)
  kube-system                kube-proxy-gke-spokesman-cluster-default-pool-d70d068f-wjtk    100m (10%)    0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)
  kube-system                l7-default-backend-5d5b9874d5-cgczj                            10m (1%)      10m (1%)    20Mi (1%)        20Mi (1%)
  kube-system                metrics-server-v0.2.1-7486f5bd67-ctbr2                         53m (5%)      148m (15%)  154Mi (13%)      404Mi (34%)
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits
  ------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------
  681m (72%)    296m (31%)  807312Ki (67%)   1216912Ki (102%)
```

**Here my app**

```
PROD:
API:        ASP.NET core 1.1 (microsoft/dotnet:1.1-runtime-stretch)
Frontend:   Angular app (nginx:1.15-alpine)
Admin:      Angular app (nginx:1.15-alpine)

TEST:
API:        ASP.NET core 1.1 (microsoft/dotnet:1.1-runtime-stretch)
Frontend:   Angular app (nginx:1.15-alpine)
Admin:      Angular app (nginx:1.15-alpine)

SHARDED
Database:   Postgres (postgres:11-alpine)
```

Any suggestions are more than welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are already overcommitted on memory and CPU utilization is high for a cluster that should basically be idle. Adding anything more will result in a poorly performing system. If you are just learning containers, I would wait before jumping into Kubernetes. Launch a compute instance (Google has a good container OS) and then test with just your applications in containers. Once you are comfortable with containers, take the next step to Kubernetes (everything you learned about containers applies to Kubernetes).

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley for your comment. I ran the `kubectl describe node` command after I created the cluster. I did install any pods yet.

Answer (score 3):

If you intend to run a containerized app on a single node, a [GCE instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/) could be better to begin with.

When moving into GKE, check out this [GCP's guide](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-architecture#memory_cpu) explaining resource allocation per machine type before any workload and kube-system pods. You'd still need to have estimated resources usage per app component or container, maybe from monitoring your Dev or GCE environment.

If you want to explore other alternatives on GCP for your app (e.g. App Engine supports [.NET](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/dotnet/customizing-the-dotnet-runtime)), here's a [post](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/choosing-the-right-compute-option-in-gcp-a-decision-tree) with a decision tree that might help you. I also found this [article/tutorial](https://medium.com/google-cloud/app-engine-flex-container-engine-946fbc2fe00a) about running containers on App Engine and GKE, comparing both with load tests.

Comment: I have used kops https://github.com/kubernetes/kops to deploy a 1 master and 1 node medium instance kubernetes cluster.